# Kamatz katan in "kadashim" in Vayikra 24:9

Tags: grammar-dikduk, parashas-emor

In the verse [Vayikra 24:9](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0324.htm#9) in the printed *tikkun* the first *kamatz* of the word *kadashim* (קׇֽדָשִׁ֨ים) is not *katan.* However, on [Wikisource](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%AA_%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8/%D7%98%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D) it has that first kamatz as a *kamatz katan:*

> וְהָֽיְתָה֙ לְאַהֲרֹ֣ן וּלְבָנָ֔יו וַאֲכָלֻ֖הוּ בְּמָק֣וֹם קָדֹ֑שׁ כִּ֡י קֹ֩דֶשׁ֩ **קׇֽדָשִׁ֨ים** ה֥וּא ל֛וֹ מֵאִשֵּׁ֥י יְהֹוָ֖ה חׇק־עוֹלָֽם׃

Which one is the correct?

Comment: Which printed tikkun?

Comment: According to the Tikkun Simanim (following Minchat Shai), the phrase קֹ֩דֶשׁ֩ קׇֽדָשִׁ֨ים (i.e., without a "hey" on the second word) takes a kamatz, whereas the phrase with a "hey" on the second word takes a kamatz katan.